# Javascript function not working properly for multiple row data in PHP-MySQL

Tags: javascript

I have a `PHP` script which displays the items indented by a User to get approved for the HOD.

The HOD fills the `Qty Approved` for each of the items indented.

[image]

I am using a `Javascript Function` that on clicking `APPROVE` it will check for the following conditions for each of the requisitions:

`1. Qty Approved cannot be more than Qty Indented`

`2. Quantity Approved cannot be Zero.`

`3. Quantity Approved cannot be more than Stocks Available.`

I am using the following Javascript Code:

```js
function submitForm (button){
  var x = 0;
  var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value, 10);
   if (button.value == "     APPROVE     "){
    for(x=0;x<count;x++){
     var qty_approved = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty_approved_" + x).value, 10);
     var qty_intended = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty_indented_" + x).value, 10);
     var balance = parseInt(document.getElementById("bal_" + x).value, 10);
     if (qty_approved <= 0){
      alert("Please Enter the Quantity for Approval!");
      submitOK = "false"; 
     }
     else if(qty_approved > qty_intended){
      alert("Quantity Approved " + qty_approved + " Cannot be more than quantity intended " + qty_intended + " !");
      submitOK = "false";
     }
     else if(qty_approved > balance){
      alert("Quantity Approved cannot be greater than Stock Balance!");
     }
     else{
      confirm("Are you sure you want to APPROVE the Voucher?");
     }
     if (submitOK == "false") {
      return false;
     }
     
    }
   }
   else{
    confirm("Are you sure you want to REJECT the Voucher?"); 
   }
   
  
 }
```

The HTML of the APPROVE Button:

```
<input type="submit" name="da_approve" value="     APPROVE     "  onclick="return submitForm(this)" />
```

The `PHP` code to generate the table:

```
<?php $j += $i; ?> 
<?php echo "<tr><td> $j. </td>
      <td><input type='text' name='' value=$item_desc readonly='readonly' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='qty_indented' value='$qty_intended' id='qty_indented_$i' readonly='readonly' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='' value='$rate' readonly='readonly' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='' value='$tot_cost' readonly='readonly' /></td>  
      <td><input type='text' name='bal' value='$remaining' id='bal_$i'  readonly='readonly' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='qty_approved' value='$qty_approved' id='qty_approved_$i' /></td>
      </tr>" 
    ?>
<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="<?php echo $count_sql_SIV ?>" />
```

But, The `for` loop is running only ONCE for 2 Items.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What is the value of `document.getElementById("count").value`? Your question doesn't have the HTML for that element.

Comment: @Andy, I have modified the code, and added the `count` element from the HTML form

Comment: And what is the value of `$count_sql_SIV`? Is it two? The other thing is that your function will return `false` if at any time `submitOK` is `false`, so there could be something in the data in the second iteration that's causing the function to quit.

Comment: @Andy, Yes, the `count` value is 2. That is what I don't understand. It seems to submit the form after 1 iteration even if I select `Cancel` in the `confirm()`

Comment: To be honest I think you should separate the checking of the data and the confirmation/alerts of the data. Have the function analyse the data and perhaps colour the background of the table cells that aren't correct in red so that the user knows the data needs to be changed, and then once the corrections have been made submit the form.

Comment: You're not acting upon the result of either of the confirms.. you need if(confirm(...)){} kind of thing.  As it stands it's just a message.  And I agree with Andy - separate the checking.  If that whole table was 'wrong' the user would get a blizzard of alerts.